# How to update Date on two different views into a fragment xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I implements DatePicker.IOnDateChangedListener in a fragment class. How can i use updateDateHandler for two different views which are in the fragment.

Actually i need to know the way by which i can implements DapePicker.IOnDateChangedListener and use it for two different views.

Answer (score 0):

You can test what the `Id` is of the `View` that is received in the listener and act accordingly.

Given this layout of two DatePickers that share one listener:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datepicker_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datepicker_two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Your listener can contain a `switch` (or a series of `if/else`):

```
public void OnDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
{
    switch (view.Id)
    {
        case Resource.Id.datepicker_one:
            Log.Debug("SO", $"DatePicker One Value: {view.DateTime}");
            break;
        case Resource.Id.datepicker_two:
            Log.Debug("SO", $"DatePicker Two Value: {view.DateTime}");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir,

How can i update the value of those view? previously i doing this for only one view and i use updateDateHandler for update the value.

   this.updateDateHandler += delegate (object sender, DateTime e)
            {
                dateOfBirth.Text = e.ToString("d");}

But i can not update for two views. sender got the object of whole class. Even i make my view Object public. It update both of the view with the last value. I can not distinguish the views.